# Jump on slideUp jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm trying to create a material design Stepper using Materializecss and I'm almost there, but I'm having some strange issue with the slideUp animation on each step.
When it's just about to end, there is an abrupt jump. I prepared a jsFiddle for you to see, but I'm also writing the code in here:

https://jsfiddle.net/c3xLwzru/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col l8 m10 s12 offset-l2 offset-m1">
        <h3 class="light center-align purple-text text-darken-4">Subscription</h3>
        <div class="card">
           <div class="card-content">

              <ul class="stepper">
                 <li class="step">
                    <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark"><div class="number">1</div>Step 1</div>
                    <div class="step-content">
                       Example 1
                       <div class="step-actions">
                          <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn" type="submit">SEGUINTE</button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li class="step">
                    <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark"><div class="number">2</div>Step 2</div>
                    <div class="step-content">
                       Example 2
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li class="step">
                    <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark"><div class="number">3</div>Step 3</div>
                    <div class="step-content">
                       Example 3
                    </div>
                 </li>
              </ul>

           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS (adding to Materializecss):**

```
ul.stepper {
   max-width: 800px;
}

.step:not(:last-child) {
   position: relative;
   margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.step:not(:last-child).active {
   margin-bottom: 36px;
}

.step-title {
   margin: 0 -20px;
   cursor: pointer;
   margin-bottom: 8px;
   padding: 12px 44px 24px 20px;
   display: block;
}

.step-title:hover {
   background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

.step.active .step-title {
   font-weight: 500;
}

.step-title .number {
   margin-right: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   height: 28px;
   width: 28px;
   color: white;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   border-radius: 50%;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 28px;
   font-weight: 400;
}

.step.active .number {
   background-color: #9C27B0;
}

.step-content {
   display: none;
   height: calc(100% - 132px);
   width: inherit;
   overflow: auto;
   margin-left: 41px;
   margin-right: 24px;
}

.stepper>.step:not(:last-child)::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
   left: 13.5px;
   width: 1px;
   height: calc(100% - 24px);
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.stepper>.step.active:not(:last-child)::after {
   height: calc(100% - 12px);
}

.step-actions {
   display: none;
   padding-top: 16px;
   margin-right: 24px;
}

.step.active .step-actions {
   display: block;
}
```

**And JS, using jQuery:**

```
$(document).on("click", '.stepper .step-title:not(.active)', function () {
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   $(this).next().stop().slideDown('slow');
   $(".step.active").not($(this).parent()).find(".step-content").stop().slideUp('slow');
   $(".step.active").not($(this).parent()).removeClass('active');
});
```

I don't know what to do anymore. I tried everything and I couldn't find a reason for them to jump, man.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **margin-bottom: 8px** on **.step-title** and add **margin-top: 8px** to **.step-content**.

It should stop abrupt jump

Comment: Woah, actually worked! Just remove `margin-bottom` did the job. But why does it happens? I mean, the margin should be there anyway, with visible `.step-content` or not.

Comment: An older question, but I'll answer anyway: the slide function of jquery only adds element styles that affect the height for the animation. not for any margins as these can vary easily. So while the height is reduced to zero, the margin is still there and only after jquery adds a "display: none" for the element style, the whole thing disappears. So any border or backgrounds that are still visible at this point due to the margin will still be seen and abruptly disappear as the "display: none" is applied. Hence the "jumping".